# kafka-node start consume from last offset

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using kafka-node to consume messages from a specific Kafka topic. When I restart my node server, it init my consumer as expected, but it's default behavior is to start consume from offset 0 while my goal is to receive only new messages (aka start consume from current offset). I didn't find a way to achieve   that from the API documentation. Anyone knows if its supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked this question in kafka-node github issues ([link](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/388)) and got an answer. It is now available (from v0.4.0). The following snippet worked for me:

```
consumerClient = new kafka.Client('localhost:2181');

/* Print latest offset. */
var offset = new kafka.Offset(consumerClient);

offset.fetch([{ topic: 'myTopic', partition: 0, time: -1 }], function (err, data) {
        var latestOffset = data['myTopic']['0'][0];
        console.log("Consumer current offset: " + latestOffset);
});

var consumer = new kafka.HighLevelConsumer(
        consumerClient,
        [
            { topic: 'myTopic', partition: 0, fromOffset: -1 }
        ],
        {
            autoCommit: false
        }
);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I am not able to find `HighLevelConsumer`

Answer (score 2):

Similar answer; this will retrieve all offsets for each partition and will set the offset to the highest value, minus 1, to consume the last published message for given topic.

```js
var offset = new kafka.Offset(client)
offset.fetchLatestOffsets([topic], (err, offsets) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`error fetching latest offsets ${err}`)
        return
    }
    var latest = 1
    Object.keys(offsets[topic]).forEach( o => {
        latest = offsets[topic][o] > latest ? offsets[topic][o] : latest
    })
    consumer.setOffset(topic, 0, latest-1)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wants to receive only new messages, you have to set the following property before the creating consumer instance:
auto.offset.reset=latest

Comment: Where should I do that?

Comment: /* Before you creating KafkaConsumer Instance, you have to set the property. */
props.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "latest"); /* earliest, latest */


KafkaConsumer<?, ?> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the JavaScript (node js) API? Looks like c++

Comment: No. This is java code. You can set the property in server.properties and try

Comment: I've tried to put in in the configuration file - server.properties but it doesn't work..

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: JavaScript, via kafka-node lib as I wrote in the question

Comment: kafka.consumer("my-consumer-group-2").join({
    "format": "binary",
    "auto.offset.reset": "latest"
  }

Comment: You can refer this link : http://www.confluent.io/blog/getting-started-with-kafka-in-node.js-with-the-confluent-rest-proxy